# How customize reactstrap dropdown in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Created sample application with ReactJS and install reactstrap for boostrap. I use dropdown components in application that is working fine. code is

```
<Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
    <DropdownToggle caret>
      Dropdown
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

but i have to change .

> Like currently they passing text only

. But

> I have to pass 3 things like icon,heading and sub heading

so can I change DropdownItem.js code for this type of customization ?

I have to make dropdown similar to this image http://prntscr.com/f34zoo

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to have custom menu items:

As it is specified on [the official website](http://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns):

```
<Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
   <span
      onClick={this.toggle}
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownOpen}
      >
   Custom Dropdown Content
   </span>
   <DropdownMenu>
      <div onClick={this.toggle}>
          <i class="some-icon"/>
          <h3>Some heading</h3>
          <p>Some sub heading</p>
      </div>
      <div onClick={this.toggle}>
          <i class="some-icon"/>
          <h3>Some heading</h3>
          <p>Some sub heading</p>
      </div>
      <div onClick={this.toggle}>
          <i class="some-icon"/>
          <h3>Some heading</h3>
          <p>Some sub heading</p>
      </div>
   </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: Ok understand so we dont need to change DropdownItem.js for custom styled dropdown right?

Comment: yes you can pass down your HTML elements instead of just text, and then customize it with CSS.

Comment: Please check "Custom Dropdown" section.

Answer (score 5):

There is a better way to do it.
If you want the dropdown toggle to be like:

```
<div>
  <span>{selectedShop ? selectedShop.shopCity : ''}</span>
  <FaChevronDown />
</div>
```

Then your DropdownToggle should be like (see the `tag` attribute):

```
<DropdownToggle tag="div">
  <span>{selectedShop ? selectedShop.shopCity : ''}</span>
  <FaChevronDown />
</DropdownToggle>
```

The tag props takes the html tag for wrapping the dropdown toggle content. Now you can style ur div any way you want.

Note: By default the `tag` is a `button`.

Now, for your dropdown items. You can simply do something like this:

```
<DropdownItem onClick={() => onShopChange(shopToMap)}>
  <i class="some-icon" />
  <h3>Some heading</h3>
  <p>Some sub heading</p>{' '}
</DropdownItem>
```

Note: Even for `DropdownItem` you can specify `tag` prop.

Comment: very simple and clean solution

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, gives you  total control on how the toggle is rendered